# Why do we add 'es' termination in 'gesundes Essen'?

Tags: declension, accusative

For example:

> Ich werde häufiger **gesundes Essen** statt Pizza kaufen.

Comment: What ending would you have expected and what is your level of German (grammar)?

Comment: I have done much self learning with online resources, but mostly informal training like duolingo, DW resources, etc. So I don't have a solid grammar foundation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how the declination of adjectives work. You choose an ending depending on article (definite, indefinite), gender, case and number (singular or plural) of corresponding noun. In your case you have no article, neuter noun in singular form, accusative case. That is why you have to end an adjective with "-es".

See the [tables of declinations](http://www.udoklinger.de/Deutsch/Grammatik/Adjektiv.htm).

Comment: *article* and *form* ain't grammar terms. Correct is *gender* and *number*. Concerning the former, it's not a matter of style. It's misleading since *die* is an article and it doesn't fully determine the number/gender.

Comment: @c.p. I edited a bit. And _gender_ is not _article_. As for article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)

Answer (score 1):

To native english speakers use of the accusative or any form of declension is an obscure concept that is hard to explain in a few words here. I leave that to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declension#Modern_English

Many languages still use declension and it is just one of those things that a language student has to come to grips with. 
Very simplified:
Nouns can be used in a sentence as an subject or an object.
If it used as a subject it is used in its normal form like you find it in the dictionary.
Declension means that if a noun is used in a sentence as an **object** it is marked as an object by different endings. Adjectives and pronouns related to that noun are marked with endings as well {or change altogether}. 
Once you get your head around that concept then the next step is to understand the use of the 4 main cases of declension - that is: when and why do you use Accusative? when and why Dativ ect. 
Start with : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_declension

The last step is the memorisation of the endings table.
Good luck. {don't be disheartened - declension is usually the last thing a language student perfects and if you learn languages only to communicate it is NOT!! important} Yes, every native german speaker will spot the mistake but EVERY native german speaker will understand you even if you get the declension wrong.

The case above: adjective declension (gesund) / Neuter noun, singular (Das Essen), no article used, Accusative case,  ending is "es"
see 
http://germanforenglishspeakers.com/adjectives/adjective-declensions/

Answer (score 1):

In German (and I guess in most other languages like English) there are three ways how adjectives can be used:

- **Prädikative Adjektive**
  Adjectives are used as part of a predicate. In this case the predicate consists of a verb that is a form of »sein«, »bleiben«  or »werden« (to be, to stay, to become) plus an adjective:

  > Der Apfel **ist *rot***. - The apple **is *red***.
  >   Walter **bleibt *stur***. - Walter **stays *stubborn***.
  >   Dein Essen **wird *kalt***. - Your meal **becomes *cold***.
- **Adverbiale Adjektive**
  The adjective is used in an adverbial manner. (In english you often add the suffix -ly to the adjective to turn it into an adverb.) You build it the same way as predicative adjectives, but after any other verb than »sein«, »bleiben«  or »werden«:

  > Otto **geht *langsam***. - Otto **walks *slowly***.
  >   Walter **spricht *laut***. - Walter **speaks *loudly***.
  >   Die Suppe **schmeckt *gut***. - The soup **tastes *well***.
- **Attributive Adjektive**
  Put the adjective between an article or pronoun and a noun to use it as an attribute of that noun:

  > **Der *rote* Apfel** schmeckt gut. - **The *red* apple** tastes well.
  >   **Dein *neues* Kleid** ist schön. - **Your *new* dress** is beautiful.
  >   **Das *kleine* Baby** schläft schon. - **The *little* baby** is already sleeping.

  this works also without article/pronoun. Just put it in front of a noun:

  > ***Rote* Schuhe** sind oft teuer. - ***Red* shoes** often are expensive.

---

If you use an adjective as an attribute, then is has to be declined together with the noun. This means:

- **number**
  If the noun is **singular** or **plural**, then the attribute must be in the same grammatical number.
- **gender**
  German has three grammatical genders: **männlich** (male; literally: *man-like*), **weiblich** (female, literally: *woman-like*) and **sächlich** (literally: *thing-like*, but you might better use the term *neuter*). A nouns attribute must always have the same gender as the noun to which it belongs.
- **gramamtical case**
  In German a noun can be used in one of those four grammatical cases: **Nominativ, Genitiv, Dativ, Akkusativ**. If a noun has an attribute, the attribute must always be used in the same case.

This means: If an adjective is used as an attribute, than there are:

> **2** numbers times
>   **3** genders times
>   **4** cases
>   giving **24** different ways how this attributive adjective can be used.

Those 24 different ways are marked by suffixes that are added to the adjective. But there are not 24 different endings, there are way less, so that many combinations of number, gender and case use the same suffix.

But be careful: The way how adjectives are declined does not only depend on number, gender and case of the noun. It also depends on the kind of article (definite or indefinite article) that stands before the attribute:

> **Der *alte*** Mann isst Brot. - **The *old*** man eats bread.
>   **Ein *alter*** Mann isst Brot. - **An *old*** man eats bread.

Also a missing article can change the way of declension:

> **Das *kalte*** Wasser ist frisch. - **The *cold*** water is fresh.
>   ***Kaltes*** Wasser ist frisch. - ***Cold*** water is fresh.

For more details ask your teacher or consult other resources.

---

In your case you use the **neuter** noun »das Essen« (food) **without an article**, in **singular** number and in **accusative** case. The suffix for this combination is »-es«, so the adjective »**gesund**« must be used as »**gesund*es***« if it is used as an attribute.

- predicative

  > Das Essen ist **gesund**.
- adverbial

  > Das Essen schmeckt **gesund**.
- attributiv

  > Das **gesunde** Essen schmeckt gut. (Nominativ mit bestimmtem Artikel)
  >   **Gesundes** Essen schmeckt gut. (Nominativ ohne Artikel)
  >   Ich habe Lisa **gesundes** Essen gebracht. (Akkusativ)
  >   Die Wirkung des **gesunden** Essens ist umstritten. (Genitiv)
  >   Die Wirkung von **gesundem** Essen ist umstritten. (Dativ)

  (all examples are in singular; »Essen« can't be used in plural)

Answer (score -1):

The correct sentence would be:

> Ich werde häufiger gesundes Essen statt Pizza kaufen

Here *gesundes Essen* is Akkusativ (*Wen/was werde ich kaufen?*; Adjektiv ohne Artikel) of *das gesunde Essen* (Neutrum, Nominativ, Singular).

Comment: This doesn't explain why. Moreover, people who learn German don't know which question should be asked to guess the case (*Wen/was werde ich kaufen?* doesn't help).

Comment: It does explain why (to somebody who knows a bit of German grammar). Will try to expand in case user3063381 does not.

Comment: I asked user3063381 for clarification on his/her level of German.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the level of a certain user is. Questions on this site should always be of general interest, and so should an answer always assume that there will be users that have absolutely no knowledge about German or at least about the topic at hand. Furthermore, it's obvious that OP has little knowledge of German. With that being said, I think it's reasonable to edit the answer and include much more details about what's going on here.